# Surjectivity of the Albanese map of the moduli space of stable vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I have a naive question:(I saw that it is related to [relative K-theory](http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_2002__130_2_253_0) of Hodge-Deligne and also [Nadel-Chern-Weil theory](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002080050100) )

Let $\mathcal M (r, d)$ be the moduli space of stable vector bundles of rank $r$ with a fixed determinant of degree $d$ on a projective variety $X$. Then when the Albanese map $\mathcal M (r, d)\to Alb(\mathcal M (r, d))$ is surjective.?

Comment: Is $X$ a curve? If not, what is the degree?

Comment: @abx , many thank for your interesting comment, "however" we can define the degree for a reflexive sheaf, vector bundles,.. see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69096/why-is-the-degreerank-ratio-of-a-vector-bundle-called-its-slope

Comment: Then you need to choose an ample class on $X$. And what is the Albanese map? Your $\mathcal{M}(r,d)$ is neither projective, nor normal in general.

Comment: It is quasi-projective